# MySQL Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: mysql, locking, timeout

I have got the error `Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`. What are the reasons for this and how to solve the problem? FYI: `innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 100` in MySQL config file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is problem of **lock contention**, which ultimately result in a time-out on one of the lock. Here are a few suggestions:

- Make sure you have the correct indexes which result in **row-level** locks not **table-level** lock. This will reduce the contention.
- Make sure you have indexes on the **foreign key** constraints. To check the relational constraints during `insert` or `update`, some database lock the whole referenced table if there is no such index (don't know if this is the case of MySQL)
- If problem is still here, try to make the transaction faster/smaller. Again, this will reduce the contention on the database.
- Increase the timeout but keep the value reasonable

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening on a high-trafficked system where transactions take a long time (i.e. tables are locked for a long time)? If so, you might want to look into your transaction code to make them shorter / more granular / more performant.